# Restrict http proxy access without restricting socket access

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

Let's say I have enabled `mod_proxy` , `mod_proxy_fcgi` and `mod_proxy_http`  in my Apache 2.4 server. I use `mod_proxy_fcgi`  to access my PHP-FPM service (socket not tcp). I know I can restrict access to my proxy by using  [<Proxy>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#access) directive. My Problem is that I want to restrict access based on Proxy itself not proxied content. For example, this:

```
<Proxy "*">
  Require ip 192.168.0
</Proxy>
```

will restrict access to my PHP-FPM and users will see `403 Access denied`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by "I want to restrict access based on Proxy itself not proxied content"?

Note, in general, <Proxy> blocks are for configuring forward proxies, not reverse, which is what you have. In your case you can just use a Location block

```
<Location "/">
  Require ip 192.168.0
</Location>
```

Comment: Assume I have two php-fpm pools.One on port `9000`, the other one on port `9500`. I want different one to be more public than the other one.

Comment: And how are you deciding which FPM pool to use in your Apache httpd configuration?

Comment: I use vhost I know I can restrict them with vhost but I was wondering if I can do it without that. I like it to be in one place not in 50 different vhost directive.

Comment: Apologies I kinda asked an incomplete question. If both pools were in the same vhost how you you chose between them in theApache configuration?

Comment: There is only one pool in each vhost.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44344/discussion-between-undone-and-unbeliever).